# I have inherited professional studio backdrops with motorized rollersystem. Where can I find a market to sell them?

Tags: product-photography

What is the best way to sell preowned studio backdrops and motorized roller system? My Dad was a photographer for most of my life & recently I inherited all of his equipment.
Any suggestions other than eBay & Craigslist?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not craigslist? It the cheapest, free, and if you are in a city or near a large urban/suburban area, used by a lot of people.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about the practice of photography.

Comment: Condolences on your loss.

Comment: Thank you for your comments & suggestions. I’ll keep tryin in the other markets. It’s overwhelming when you’re not savy with all the gear. 
Sorry for your inconvenience Michael C.

Comment: @DHurd It's not about inconvenience. It's about trying to keep this site focused on the art and practice of actually taking photographs.

Answer (score 1):

Selling photography equipment is no different than selling anything else: post it to as many marketplaces as you can. There's eBay, Craigslist, OfferUp, NextDoor, and on and on.

If you are in a decent sized city, there's probably a dedicated photography store like a https://prophotosupply.com or https://www.bhphotovideo.com that would take in your used gear for resale.

There's online only sites as well like https://www.adorama.com and https://www.keh.com that may be interested.

Then there are forums that might be keen on gear sales like https://www.fredmiranda.com/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/photography/.

And finally, there's the old school, tried and true method of cold calling. There's a finite number of studios in your area, location photographers, high school photo classes, community college photo classes, and university art programs...search your area for them and their contact info and then send them a message.

If the money means less to you than finding a good home for your father's gear, such that a future generation of photographers is aided by his life's acquisitions, then I'd encourage you to donate the gear to an art program in your area (there's probably a tax deduction you can take, too!).

Comment: small point of order... Adorama is a brick-and-mortar camera store just like B&H, only on a smaller scale. Well, unless things have changed... admittedly last time I walked into the Adorama store was about 2003 or so.

Comment: Would the -1 voter actually...you know...give a reason for the vote?

Comment: wasn't me :shrug: